# $(document).ready doesn't work under MVC4 project

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am just inserting

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("!!!");
});
```

as usually into

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sign Up";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_WebSite.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/JavaScript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("!!!");
    });

</script>

<h2>Sign Up</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
{

}

}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

but I cannot see alert() message...

other things of **jQuery** are working fine at this page...

What do I am missing?

Any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any error in firebug console ?

Comment: Why not use "text/javascript" inside of Camel Cased "text/JavaScript". Not that that was the problem but anyway. :) I think Visual Studio Intellisense writes "text/javascript" for you?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can see jQuery is referenced after your code if you inspect the html.

Default project comes with an optional scripts section that will be rendered after jQuery reference in the layout, that's where your code should go.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sign Up";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_WebSite.cshtml";
}



<h2>Sign Up</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
{

}

}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("!!!");
    });

    </script>
}
```